# Get Custom post with ID

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

How do I get a custom post by its ID? I want to display a single post from custom post using its ID. I tried `'post_type' => 'homepage', 'post_id' => '717'` but it didnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply don't need to specify a `post_type` when calling `get_post()`. The `ID` for any sort of post is *unique*  among the whole DB-posts table. So if you're calling a post with ID = 17

```
$id = 17;
$post = get_post( $id );
```

then you'll simply get this single post.

Note, according the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post), when using `get_post`

> You must pass a variable containing an integer (e.g. $id). A literal integer (e.g. get_post(7)) will cause a fatal error (Only variables can be passed for reference or Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference).

Comment: Hi,
I tried using below code but it didnt help. am I missing something here?

`<?php query_posts('p=794'); if(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
          <div class="advanced-image"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'home-vertical'); ?></div>
          <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
          <h3><a href="/about/">Learn More</a></h3>
        <?php endif;?>
  </div>`

I did same with other posts as well.

Thanks

Comment: What's that? Why making a loop (for a _SINGLE_ post!?!) instead using a simple output of the data we showed you above?