# Are Post IDs Unique Across all Post Types?

Tags: custom-post-types, id

I thought Wordpress post IDs were only unique within each post type, so that the first instance of each post type would have an ID of 1 and they would count up from there. In order to get a specific instance of a custom post type, you would have to designate that post type in the query.

But according to [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/57225) on another question, post IDs are actually unique to each post, regardless of post type. I checked in the posts table for the site I'm working on now, and sure enough the post IDs are unique. But I'm sure I read somewhere (a couple years ago) that they weren't.

Did Wordpress change the way it sets post IDs, or have I just been wrong this whole time?

Comment: They've been unique as long as i can remember, it's entirely possible whatever you read was either incorrect or the person that wrote it was confusing post IDs with something else(ie. made a mistake).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All post types are stored in the same `posts` table, so they have to use different post IDs. That was always the case, since the the post type `page` was introduced [2005 with version 1.5](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_1.5).